# Get 'text' from popup in arcgis javascript API

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

[image]

I am using webmap id to show the map in my website. I am using custom popup and taking the feature content into the popup,

Here is the complete script:

```
    // getting the basemapurl
var basetemplateurl = jQuery("#basetemplateurl").val();
var webmapid = jQuery("#webmapid").val();
var arcgisapi = jQuery("#arcgisapi").val();
var browser;

// The map classes and includes
require([
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/WebMap",
  "esri/widgets/Search",
  "esri/widgets/Zoom",
  "esri/widgets/Locate",
  "esri/popup/content/ImageMediaInfo",
  "esri/form/elements/FieldElement",
], function (MapView, WebMap, Search, Zoom, Locate, ImageMediaInfo,FieldElement) {
  // The webmap declaration
  var webmap = new WebMap({
    portalItem: {
      id: webmapid,
    },
  });

  /* The map view, the webmapid assigned. The WebMap instance created */
  var view = new MapView({
    map: webmap,
    container: "map",
    center: [-95.9406, 41.26],
    zoom: 16,
    maxZoom: 21,
    minZoom: 13,
    basemap: "topo",

    // remove the default zoom controlls
    ui: {
      components: ["attribution"],
    },
  });

  webmap
    .load()
    .then(function () {
```

Load the basemap to get its layer created
Only loading the basemap to avoid loading the layers at the begining

```
      return webmap.basemap.load();
    })
    .then(function () {
```

Grab all the layers and load them
let allLayers = webmap.allLayers;
// console.log(allLayers);

```
      var promises = allLayers.map(function (layer) {
        return layer.load();
      });
      return Promise.all(promises.toArray());
    })
    .then(function (layers) {


      var removeLayerArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,11];
      removeLayerArray.forEach(function (element) {
        webmap.remove(layers[element]);
      });

      var popupTemplate;
```

Sets the location of the popup to the center of the view

```
   Position of the popup in relation to the selected feature.
      view.popup.alignment = "top-center";
      // To disable the collapse functionality
      view.popup.collapseEnabled = false;
      // A spinner appear at the pointer
      view.popup.spinnerEnabled = false;
      // To disable the dock (The popup will be appear in bottom or any corner of the window)
      view.popup.dockEnabled = false;
      // Disable the pagination
      // view.popup.featureNavigationEnabled = false;
      view.popup.featureNavigation = false;
      // Popup template details, Keep only name and address in the popup and avoid all other details
      

     
      view.popup.defaultPopupTemplateEnabled = false;

      view.popup.actionsMenuEnabled = false;
```

To show the on-street park image in the popup

```
      view.on("click", function (event) {
        // view.popup.location = event.mapPoint;
        // view.goTo(view.popup.location);

        // keep a delay to align the popup and the pointer together positioned to the map center
        // Add animation only if the browser not IE

        if (browser != "IE") {
          setTimeout(function () {
            view.goTo(event.mapPoint, {
              duration: 500,
            });
          }, 500);
        }
      });

      // Only for IE 11 add the svg file while loading the page
      if (browser == "IE") {
        searchIcon();
      }
```

Apply the name and content to each layers except the meter layers

```
      for (let i = 2; i < layers.length; i++) {
        var template = {
          title: function () {
            if(i==4 || i==3 || i==2){
              return "Rates";
            }
            else if (i == 5) {
              return "{LOCATIONNAME}";
            } else if (i == 6) {
              return "Accessible Stalls, On-street";
            } else {
              return "{Name}";
            }
          },
          content: function (feature) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var address = feature.graphic.attributes.Address;
            var facilityID = feature.graphic.attributes.FACILITYID;
            var numberofstalls = "";


            var showpopup = "";
            if (i != 6 &&i != 4 &&i != 3 &&i != 2 ) {
              showpopup =
                '<div class="right"><div href="#" id="popupRight" class="toggle"><p onClick="openPopupDetails(' +
                facilityID +
                ')">+</p></div></div>';
            }

            // Condition for showing the handicapped layers 6,7
            if (i == 4 || i==3 || i==2) {
             
              address =
                "<div>Tier rates: " +
                feature.graphic.attributes.Hours +
                "</div>";
            }
            if (i == 5) {
              address = feature.graphic.attributes.LOCATIONADDRESS;
              numberofstalls =
                "<div>Accessible Stalls: " +
                feature.graphic.attributes.NUMEROFSTALLS +
                "</div>";
            }
            if (i == 6) {
              address =
                "<div class='onstreet_image'><a href=" +
                feature.graphic.attributes.IMAGE_URL +
                " target='_blank'>Photo</a></div>";
            }
            div.innerHTML =
              '<div id="popup_address">' +
              address +
              "</div>" +
              numberofstalls +
              showpopup;
            return div;
          },
          outFields: [
            "Name",
            "Address",
            "FACILITYID",
            "LOCATIONADDRESS",
            "LOCATIONNAME",
            "NUMEROFSTALLS",
            "IMAGE_URL",
            "tier",
            "Hours",
            "CreationDate"
          ],
        };
        layers[i].popupTemplate = template;
      }

      // To close the popup when hit on esc button
      document.onkeyup = function (evt) {
        var key = evt.keyCode;
        if (key == 27) {
          view.popup.close();
        }
      };
```

});

I am collecting the details for popup like this,

```
feature.graphic.attributes.FACILITYID
```

But this wont work in the case of text as the text is not coming under attribute (Attribute table). How can I access the text 'This is a text' ? To access the text, the text should be in field list?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the full implementation / definition of your template?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: I can not relate the popup content on the image to the definition on the code. By looking at the image it seems you have at least two contents, one type "fields" and one type "text". But in your code the definition is totally different.

Comment: Your a couple of code snippet can't reproduce your screen map. Can you make two source. One for whole HTML and one for script?  It will help to understand your problem.